# copy only tables with data from one database to another database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two database , `dbOne`(version - 10.50.1600 - locate in office server )  and `dbTwo`(version - 10.0.1600 - locate in my local server) .
I want to copy `dbOne`'s tables with data to `dbTwo` .
Is there any way or script to do it ? I don't want to upgrade my local server-version !

Answer (score 2):

Here are several options you can try:

**Export/import wizard**: If you only want to copy tables and don’t want to bother with relationships and such this is probably the quickest way to do this.

**Generate scripts wizard**: Generate scripts for all tables you want to migrate. Right click on the database -> Tasks -> Generate scripts -> select only tables you want to migrate. 
Also make sure that you manually review execution order of scripts because SSMS doesn’t order these correctly be default (doesn’t take dependencies into account)

**Third party tools**: There are many database comparison tools out there you can use for this such as Red-Gate’s SQL Compare, ApexSQL Diff and many others…. All of these are premium tools but you can get the job done in trial mode.

Answer (score 1):

Natively, if the  database is small then Import/Export works fine.

For large database, BCP out and BCP IN is the a good way - fast and efficient.

See my answer and the script https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/43232/8783

Answer (score -1):

If you have tcp connectin between two databases you can make linked serve.
then you can query your table on onther server.
in SQL MGM studio under object explorer there art node for linked servers.
You can easly add one. 
after that you can do something like

insert into tableone. 
lsect * from [linked server].sorucedatabse.dbo.tableone